# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined after transpiling using babel and loading into browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs, ecmascript-5

I need to transpile a javascript file written with ES6/7 syntax into ES5 and embed it dynamically into a webpage. This is how I am trying to transpile.

```
const babel = require("@babel/core");

const es15Code = babel.transform(sourceJavascript, {
    "presets": [
        ["@babel/preset-env",{
            useBuiltIns: "usage",
            corejs: 3,
            targets: {
                "browsers": "> 0.2%, not dead"
            }
        }]
    ]
});
```

The transpile works fine but as seen below it introduces a series of `require` calls:

[image]

and thus when loaded in the browser, throws an error saying `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`. How could I prevent this error? What can I do here?

Comment: Can you add details of your package.json please

Comment: If you want to use `import` and `export`, then it makes no sense to transpile to ES5 (modules are ES6); if you want to transpile, use a module bundler, like Webpack, that supports `require` function